# Why won't Cairo-Dock recognize the icons for Chrome app links?

Tags: google-chrome, cairo-dock

In Chrome, I've used the 'Create Application Shortcuts' option to add links to apps on my desktop. The appear with their favicon, but when I move them to cairo-dock, the favicon is not recognized, and I'm not sure where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a slightly different problem but with a similar solution I feel. When I created a prism shortcut which I believe is probably treated in the same or similar way.

1. The Icon will be here `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps`
2. The desktop file will be in `~/desktop` if you open it in gedit you will see the Icon reference at the bottom.
3. The fav Icon is small 16*16 and is a png so it will look crap on your cairo dock so see if you can find a svg replacement.

Once you have it there is a guide here on a couple of different ways to change the Icon on your dock [How To – Configuring Cairo-Dock](http://lusule.wordpress.com/2008/08/02/how-to-configuring-cairo-dock/#5)

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I didn't find a good answer in one place, but with hints from various sources came up with the following way to add Google Chrome apps to Cairo Dock so that they work correctly (correct icon, no duplication of icons, no getting mixed up with the main Chrome or Chromium window, etc.)

- Find a suitable icon image (a quick Google image search will do it; best to find images with transparent backgrounds) and save
- Install the Chrome app launcher from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher so that you can open the chrome apps, then open the app you want to create a dock item for
- Go to Cairo-Dock menu -> + Add -> Custom Launcher

  - Launcher's name = [app's name]
  - Image's name or path = the image you saved earlier
  - Extra parameters / Class of the program: use the [Grab] button and click somewhere on the open Chrome app window so that a value beginning crx_ appears in the input box here
  - Copy the part of the value that just appeared not including the crx_ at the beginning (this is the app id)
  - Command to launch =

    ```
    chromium-browser --app-id=[the value on the clipboard]
    ```

    or

    ```
    google-chrome --app-id=[the value on the clipboard]
    ```
  - Apply

(If you use KDE you can also get each chrome app's window settings remembered individually using Special Window Settings and setting the Window Title to Exact Match.)

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem, but while I can get the icon/launch from your suggestion, Cairo-Dock then puts it in with the main Chrome window. Any suggestions on how to fix that?